# Using GPRecordSet as output parameter in Python Toolbox?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, python-toolbox

I would like to use a GPRecordSet in my python toolBox as an output parameter.

This geoprocessing will be share on my ArcgGIS server and in my ArcGIS portal.
I haven't see any documentation on how to use it.

Can someone give me a simple example to know how to use it?

Comment: Using a GPFeatureSet or GPRecordSet as output is pretty uncommon. Can you explain the output of your tool (or will it be a service?) Typically you'd just use FeatureClass or Table as an output.

Comment: I would like to show a table in the result of geoprocessing widget, of portal for arcgis. http://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/gp-parameter-types.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever processing your script is doing, set the final output to TABLE (not GPRecordSet). If you were to create a simple model with the tool Copy Rows and set the output parameter, its a TABLE output. Follow this same pattern for your PYT. When you publish a GP Service outputs become hardcoded (the end user cannot set them). The publishing process will change the output to a GPRecordSet per the REST interface, as it should. Let the system do this work for you as its easier to create the tool with the table output parameter.

After publishing, the WAB understands table (gprecordset) as an output from a GP Service and will display it when that result comes back.

If this doesn't answer your question I suggest you add more information on where your problem is: creating the tool, publishing the tool, creating the web application, etc.

Comment: I had several errors and you with this i resolve all of it.